# Count function on group by query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, group-by

Assuming I got a table as this:

```
TransActions(Id, ArticleId, DateBought, DateSold)
```

DateSold may be null if this Transaction hasn't been sold yet. For every ArticleId I want to list how many Transactions have been Bought and Sold so far. The problem is it seems like `GROUP BY` is not the way to go in my case. **The query I have tried:**

```
SELECT `ArticleId`, count(!ISNULL(DateBought)) AS `Bought`, count(!ISNULL(DateSold)) AS `Sold` 
FROM `Transactions` AS `Transactions` 
GROUP BY `Transactions`.`ArticleId`;
```

**The problem with the above query:**

It will always return the amount of rows GROUPED BY the ArticleId. So even though I have 22x DateSold = Null, it would return 22 as Sold. Here is a Screenshot of the original table for the above simplified problem. ArticleId is actually TradeSettingId:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` returns the number of values of the expression passed to it **that are not null**. With your query, every value is either `true` or `false` - i.e., not `null`, so all the rows are counted. To make a long story short, you just need to count the dates themselves, and leave the heavy lifting to `count`:

```
SELECT   `ArticleId`, 
         COUNT(`DateBought`) AS `Bought`,
         COUNT(`DateSold`) AS `Sold` 
FROM     `Transactions` AS `Transactions` 
GROUP BY `Transactions`.`ArticleId`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a WHERE clause with condition -

> WHERE DateBought IS NOT NULL OR DateSold IS NOT NULL